# Has lithocapture ever been seriously considered as a method of entering orbit around a planet or moon that lacks any atmosphere?

Tags: probe, mission-design, capture

What I mean by lithocapture is an orbital transfer maneuver used to reduce the velocity of a spacecraft from a hyperbolic trajectory to an elliptical orbit around the targeted celestial body where the periapsis of the hyperbolic trajectory just barely contacts the surface of the celestial body. The sliding impact would reduce orbital energy putting the spacecraft into an elliptical orbit, periapsis would then be raised above the surface by traditional means.

Is this strategy something that has ever been seriously considered by the spaceflight community? Or is it to crazy/unpredictable to ever have serious consideration? If it has been considered, are there in designs for how it would be accomplished?

Comment: The point of lithocapture would be at maximum velocity, if my head simulation is right. That would practically mean doing a long decel burn to slow the vehicle before the "descent" begins...I'm not sure you save any energy.

Comment: It is potentially a great WEAPON idea :).

Comment: How spherical of an object are you trying to hit?  Skidding into a 5m tall hill at orbital speeds would be quite the violent encounter!

Comment: Hard to prove a negative, but I can't imagine it's been seriously considered. You'd have to use a sort of "drag chain" or anchor rather than risk the spacecraft itself, and it would have to be awfully damn long...

Comment: Rephrased: Lithocapture = Controlled crash.  Lots of uncontrolled lithocaptures.

Comment: @geoffc You are thinking of [lithobraking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithobraking) which has been used intentionally as well as accidentally. I am asking specifically about cases where contact with the ground is used to reduce the orbital energy of a hyperbolic trajectory to an elliptical trajectory around the body, a 'capture'.

Comment: @lex I see. Lithocapture = Controlled ALMOST crashing.  Got it. Not sure how much better that is.  :)

Comment: I suppose if there were a runway, a [Touch-and-go landing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch-and-go_landing) might qualify. If the body were very low mass (like a [Death Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_Star) or a [cube-shaped planet](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/23951/12102) or small asteroid like [B-612](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Little_Prince#Plot)) the orbital velocity would be slow enough that conventional wheel braking could be used.

Comment: Related - similar idea: [harpoon propulsion](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/14078/harpoon-propulsion-what-would-be-the-problems)

Comment: Got a polished ball to land on?  Otherwise, splat!

Comment: @uhoh Good point about the low mass. With an asteroid one could imagine a controlled crash because the delta-v is so small.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider with low gravity, a crash would bounce off. You'd need some [balsa wood](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18856/12102) or a [crumple zone](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/4843/12102) otherwise you'd risk just bouncing back off into space. Some kind of friction or energy absorption is needed for braking. I like your user image; you might appreciate [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2358889/284619)!